# how to send/receive a data file using rtp over tcp in java

Tags: tcp, rtp

I want to write a app can transfer files peer to peer in java. does someone know an open source to send/receive a data file using rtp over tcp in java? please give me a hand, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm confused: why do you want to use video/audio streaming protocol to send data files?